# AWS API Gateway Throttling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, throttling

I'm trying to set throttling on my API and I'm trying to test to make sure my throttle settings are working.

To test this, I've set my throttle to 2 rps with 1 burst. Yes, I know that's silly, but I'm just testing my POC at this point.

I've create a simple GET method on one of my resources, which is just a MOCK integration. I'm using POSTMAN to call the URI and I get a 200.

I exported my run and am using NEWMAN (Postman CLI runner) to send 100 requests and they are all returning 200s; nothing seems to be being throttled or discarded with the 429 AWS claims should happen.

I'm looking for maybe a better way to test my throttle settings. I don't know what information I can offer.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sending the requests sequentially? Can you use the other tools which can send the requests parallelly, like `ab`, `hey` aka `boom`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Postman Collection Runner?

I created a new Postman Collection, added a GET on an endpoint that I have throttled (1 request per second). Then executed multiple Postman Collection Runner(s). Each instance of the PCR was set to run 20 instances of the request (which would ensure this would force a fail).

Creating the Postman Collection + starting multiple instances.

[image]

Once you have multiple (at least 2) PCR instances open, you can run your requests and notice the success / failures.

[image]